# How to know the size of the compressed file while filling it with gzwrite?

Tags: c, zlib

I'm writing data to a file I created with `gzopen("filename", "wb9");` using `gzwrite()`.

`gztell()` returns the offset, and thus the number of bytes, of the uncompressed data written to it.

Is there a possibility to know the compressed file-size of the output-file while writing to it? Or are there limitation due to the compression algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

> ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gzoffset OF((gzFile file));
>
> Returns the
>   current offset in the file being read or written. This offset includes
>   the count of bytes that precede the gzip stream, for example when
>   appending or when using gzdopen() for reading. When reading, the
>   offset does not include as yet unused buffered input. This information
>   can be used for a progress indicator. On error, gzoffset() returns –1.

make sure you flush the output...

Another answer, try to `stat` the file, if you just need it's size I do not see any difference between a `gz` file and any other file

https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);

struct stat {
    ...
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    ...
};
```

preety sure this will give you what you need...